# Metal fragment shader appears to write twice for a single triangle?

Tags: fragment-shader, metal

I'm trying to debug my Metal shader -- from using the GPU frame capture, I can see that the framebuffer values are twice what I would expect.

For example, I am using the ADD blend operation, with source and destination multipliers of 1.  After I draw a single triangle, the buffer value is twice what I output from the fragment shader.  That indicates to me that two writes have happened, and they added together.  But why would two writes take place when I draw a single triangle?  Anyone know?

If I change the blend operation -- for example I set the destination multiplier to 0 and the source to 1, so that successive writes don't add together -- then I see the value I expect in the buffer.  That is, I see the same value output from the shader.

I'm just wondering if there's something simple I am missing that would cause two writes to the same pixel from a fragment shader when drawing a single triangle?

Comment: It sounds like the render target was not cleared.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is it. You know how you can step through the stages of a render frame using the GPU frame debugger in XCode?  The render target starts out at 0, and immediately after my one call to DrawPrimitives the buffer has this doubled value.

Comment: Maybe you should show the exact configuration of the blending state, either your code or the frame debugger description (or both).

Comment: well -- it stopped doing it. I just spent about two hours putting together a stripped-down example using the template project, and it didn't have the problem.  Then when I went back to my main project, it didn't have the problem either!  Sheez I am not sure what I changed.  Thanks for the reply.